# How do I get weights and bias when training a dataset ?, Is there any method?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to get the integral values from a dataset by using neural networks but I wonder how I could get weights and bias to keep working on my project , I will post the pictures just for you to come up with an idea of my question.

Look at the pictures , is there any way to predict those values (integral values) by using neural networks.

[table of integral values from poettman's method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqOCZ.jpg)
[table of integral values from poettman's method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2uQG.jpg)

I have been using a python file which predicts factor of compressibility for real gases but I want to use the same structure of that file to predict integral values from those pictures.

this is the code:

```
import numpy as np


class CalculateZFactor:
    # Minimum and Maximum values used in the neural network to normalize the input and output values.
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    Ppr_min = 0
    Ppr_max = 30
    Tpr_min = 1
    Tpr_max = 3
    Z_min = 0.25194
    Z_max = 2.66

    # -------------START OF NETWORK 2-5-5-1 STRUCTURE-------------
    # Weights and Biases for the 1st layer of neurons
    wb1_5 = [
        [-1.5949, 7.9284, 7.2925],
        [-1.7917, 1.2117, 2.221],
        [5.3547, -4.5424, -0.9846],
        [4.6209, 2.2228, 8.9966],
        [-2.3577, -0.1499, -1.5063]
    ]

    # Weights and Biases for the 2nd layer of neurons
    wb2_5 = [
        [2.3617, -4.0858, 1.2062, -1.1518, -1.2915, 2.0626],
        [10.0141, 9.8649, -11.4445, -123.0698, 7.5898, 95.1393],
        [10.4103, 14.1358, -10.9061, -125.5468, 6.3448, 93.8916],
        [-1.7794, 14.0742, -1.4195, 12.0894, -15.4537, -9.9439],
        [-0.5988, -0.4354, -0.336, 9.9429, -0.4029, -8.3371]
    ]

    # Weights and Biases for the 3rd layer of neurons
    wb3_5 = [1.4979, -37.466, 37.7958, -7.7463, 6.9079, 2.8462]
    # -------------END OF NETWORK 2-5-5-1 STRUCTURE-------------

    # -------------START OF NETWORK 2-10-10-1 STRUCTURE-------------
    # Weights and Biases for the 1st layer of neurons
    wb1_10 = [
        [2.2458, -2.2493, -3.7801],
        [3.4663, 8.1167, -14.9512],
        [5.0509, -1.8244, 3.5017],
        [6.1185, -0.2045, 0.3179],
        [1.3366, 4.9303, 2.2153],
        [-2.8652, 1.1679, 1.0218],
        [-6.5716, -0.8414, -8.1646],
        [-6.1061, 12.7945, 7.2201],
        [13.0884, 7.5387, 19.2231],
        [70.7187, 7.6138, 74.6949]
    ]

    # Weights and Biases for the 2nd layer of neurons
    wb2_10 = [
        [4.674, 1.4481, -1.5131, 0.0461, -0.1427, 2.5454, -6.7991, -0.5948, -1.6361, 0.5801, -3.0336],
        [-6.7171, -0.7737, -5.6596, 2.975, 14.6248, 2.7266, 5.5043, -13.2659, -0.7158, 3.076, 15.9058],
        [7.0753, -3.0128, -1.1779, -6.445, -1.1517, 7.3248, 24.7022, -0.373, 4.2665, -7.8302, -3.1938],
        [2.5847, -12.1313, 21.3347, 1.2881, -0.2724, -1.0393, -19.1914, -0.263, -3.2677, -12.4085, -10.2058],
        [-19.8404, 4.8606, 0.3891, -4.5608, -0.9258, -7.3852, 18.6507, 0.0403, -6.3956, -0.9853, 13.5862],
        [16.7482, -3.8389, -1.2688, 1.9843, -0.1401, -8.9383, -30.8856, -1.5505, -4.7172, 10.5566, 8.2966],
        [2.4256, 2.1989, 18.8572, -14.5366, 11.64, -19.3502, 26.6786, -8.9867, -13.9055, 5.195, 9.7723],
        [-16.388, 12.1992, -2.2401, -4.0366, -0.368, -6.9203, -17.8283, -0.0244, 9.3962, -1.7107, -1.0572],
        [14.6257, 7.5518, 12.6715, -12.7354, 10.6586, -43.1601, 1.3387, -16.3876, 8.5277, 45.9331, -6.6981],
        [-6.9243, 0.6229, 1.6542, -0.6833, 1.3122, -5.588, -23.4508, 0.5679, 1.7561, -3.1352, 5.8675]
    ]

    # Weights and Biases for the 3rd layer of neurons
    wb3_10 = [-30.1311, 2.0902, -3.5296, 18.1108, -2.528, -0.7228, 0.0186, 5.3507, -0.1476, -5.0827, 3.9767]
    # -------------END OF NETWORK 2-10-10-1 STRUCTURE-------------

    # input and output of the 1st layer in 2-5-5-1 network. [,0] ==> inputs, [,1] ==> outputs
    n1_5 = np.zeros((5, 2))
    # input and output of the 2nd layer in 2-5-5-1 network. [,0] ==> inputs, [,1] ==> outputs
    n2_5 = np.zeros((5, 2))

    # input and output of the 1st layer in 2-10-10-1 network.   [,0] ==> inputs, [,1] ==> outputs
    n1_10 = np.zeros((10, 2))
    # input and output of the 2nd layer in 2-10-10-1 network.   [,0] ==> inputs, [,1] ==> outputs
    n2_10 = np.zeros((10, 2))

    TOLERANCE = 0.0001  # tolerance of DAK
    MAX_NO_Iterations = 20  # Max number of iterations for DAK

    def ANN10(self, Ppr: float, Tpr: float) -> float:
        """
        his method calculates the z-factor using a 2x10x10x1 Artificial Neural Network
         based on training data obtained from Standing-Katz and Katz charts.
         It always produces a result, but accuracy is controlled for 0<Ppr<30 and 1<Tpr<3

        :param Ppr: pseudo-reduced pressure
        :param Tpr: pseudo-reduced temperature
        :return: z factor
        """
        Ppr_n = 2.0 / (self.Ppr_max - self.Ppr_min) * (Ppr - self.Ppr_min) - 1.0
        Tpr_n = 2.0 / (self.Tpr_max - self.Tpr_min) * (Tpr - self.Tpr_min) - 1.0

        for i in range(10):
            self.n1_10[i][0] = Ppr_n * self.wb1_10[i][0] + Tpr_n * self.wb1_10[i][1] + self.wb1_10[i][2]
            self.n1_10[i][1] = log_sig(self.n1_10[i][0])

        for i in range(10):
            self.n2_10[i][0] = 0
            for j in range(len(self.n2_10)):
                self.n2_10[i][0] += self.n1_10[j][1] * self.wb2_10[i][j]
            self.n2_10[i][0] += self.wb2_10[i][10]  # adding the bias value

            self.n2_10[i][1] = log_sig(self.n2_10[i][0])

        z_n = 0
        for j in range(len(self.n2_10)):
            z_n += self.n2_10[j][1] * self.wb3_10[j]
        z_n += self.wb3_10[10]  # adding the bias value

        zAnn10 = (z_n + 1) * (self.Z_max - self.Z_min) / 2 + self.Z_min  # reverse normalization of normalized z factor.

        return zAnn10

    def ANN5(self, Ppr: float, Tpr: float) -> float:
        """
        This method calculates the z-factor using a 2x5x5x1 Artificial Neural Network
        based on training data obtained from Standing-Katz and Katz charts.
        It always produces a result, but accuracy is controlled for 0<Ppr<30 and 1<Tpr<3

        :param Ppr: pseudo-reduced pressure
        :param Tpr: pseudo-reduced temperature
        :return: z factor
        """

        Ppr_n = 2.0 / (self.Ppr_max - self.Ppr_min) * (Ppr - self.Ppr_min) - 1.0
        Tpr_n = 2.0 / (self.Tpr_max - self.Tpr_min) * (Tpr - self.Tpr_min) - 1.0

        for i in range(5):
            self.n1_5[i][0] = Ppr_n * self.wb1_5[i][0] + Tpr_n * self.wb1_5[i][1] + self.wb1_5[i][2]
            self.n1_5[i][1] = log_sig(self.n1_5[i][0])

        for i in range(5):
            self.n2_5[i][0] = 0
            for j in range(len(self.n2_5)):
                self.n2_5[i][0] += self.n1_5[j][1] * self.wb2_5[i][j]
            self.n2_5[i][0] += self.wb2_5[i][5]  # adding the bias value

            self.n2_5[i][1] = log_sig(self.n2_5[i][0])

        z_n = 0
        for j in range(len(self.n2_5)):
            z_n += self.n2_5[j][1] * self.wb3_5[j]
        z_n += self.wb3_5[5]  # adding the bias value

        zAnn5 = (z_n + 1) * (
                self.Z_max - self.Z_min) / 2 + self.Z_min  # reverse normalization of normalized z factor.

        return zAnn5

    def DAK(self, Ppr: float, Tpr: float) -> float:
        """
        This method calculates the z-factor using Dranchuk and Abou-Kassem (DAK) method.
        :param Ppr: pseudo-reduced pressure
        :param Tpr: pseudo-reduced temperature
        :return: z factor
        """
        A1 = 0.3265
        A2 = -1.07
        A3 = -0.5339
        A4 = 0.01569
        A5 = -0.05165
        A6 = 0.5475
        A7 = -0.7361
        A8 = 0.1844
        A9 = 0.1056
        A10 = 0.6134
        A11 = 0.721

        z_new = 1.0
        z_old = 1.0

        den = calculate_density(Ppr, Tpr, z_old)

        for i in range(1, self.MAX_NO_Iterations + 1):
            z_old = z_new

            z_new = (1 + (A1 + A2 / Tpr + A3 / Tpr ** 3 + A4 / Tpr ** 4 + A5 / Tpr ** 5) * den
                     + (A6 + A7 / Tpr + A8 / Tpr ** 2) * den ** 2 - A9 * (A7 / Tpr + A8 / Tpr ** 2) * den ** 5 +
                     A10 * (1 + A11 * den ** 2) * den ** 2 / Tpr ** 3 * np.exp(-1 * A11 * den ** 2))

            den = calculate_density(Ppr, Tpr, z_new)

            if np.abs(z_new - z_old) < self.TOLERANCE:
                break

        zDAK = z_new

        return zDAK


def log_sig(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-1 * x))


def calculate_density(pr: float, tr: float, z: float):
    return 0.27 * pr / tr / z
```

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't know what you try to do. Why do have hand-written weights? Where is the network (incl backprop and stuff)? Why is there a TensorFlow tag when this question is not really related to TF?